# C# WPF Access to Windows music menu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, audio-player

I have written a program that can play internet radio with the Windows Media Player component. It works fine, but I want to show the stream name in the Windows Music menu and use the buttons to play/stop the stream and switch to the next/last stream. It's a WPF-application with .NET Framework 4.7.2 and I **don't** want to use libraries (except .NET Framework and pre-installed things)!

[Windows music menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiItQ.png)

Comment: It's not called the "music menu" - it's called the `MediaSession` API.

Comment: Why are you targeting .NET 4.7.2 and not 4.8? There is no reason not to use .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.